# How to create multiple values at a time into ODOO using odoo-xml-rpc?

Tags: python, odoo

Can I create multiple values at a time using the following code?

```
id = models.execute_kw(db ,uid ,password ,'res.partner' ,'create' ,[{}]
```

Answer (score 5):

In Odoo version 12 (released on 2018-10-03) creating multiple objects in one XMLRPC call is now supported. In older Odoo versions it was not supported. The new Odoo 12 RPC API execute_kw create method can be used both with a list of objects and with a single object (Python dictionary).

The current documentation at  https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/webservices/odoo.html is not up-to-date and shows only the old way. With Odoo 12 backend you can use these both syntaxes:

```
id = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'create', [{
    'name': "New Partner",
}])

ids = models.execute_kw(db, uid, password, 'res.partner', 'create', [[{
    'name': "New Partner",
}, {
    'name': "Another New Partner",
}]])
```

The first statement creates one new model and returns the id as integer, e.g. 123. The second statement works only in Odoo 12 and creates multiple new models and returns a list of ids, e.g. [124,125]. Note the two brackets in the later syntax. If you try to run the later statement in older Odoo versions, they will raise AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'get'.

You need to modify your code with these changes:

- Provide models as a list of dictionaries.
- Make sure the models have name and other mandatory fields defined, otherwise you will get "Contacts require a name"-error.
- Add the ending parenthesis ")".

Comment: Maybe you want to see `loop the records` ?

Comment: Thanks Zety for correcting the wording. I updated the answer.

Comment: I updated the answer to include new API version in Odoo 12. The new API supports creating multiple models in one call.